# How to change margin according to other elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know the title might be not very accurate but I'll do my best to make it clear. Also if you have an idea how to make it sound better, please let me know, I'll change it.

Here's how the problem looks like: [image: row]

(Sorry about the language )

So basically I have a code based on bootstrap, it works pretty well, things look ok on different devices, but the amout of words differs in every header, so when I'm resizing the screen, the lines obviously break and header's height becomes larger, which makes the icon and the paragraph move down. And it doesn't look very nice.
 Is there a way to change the margin of the third paragraph and icon depending on first column's header? Or any way to make it look good?

Thanks in advance :)

Here's the css:

```
   h6
   {
    font-size:0.95em;
    color:rgb(52, 73, 94);
    padding:0;  
    }

   .pad
   {
    padding:15px;   
   }

   #icon
   {
    width:60px;
    display:inline-block;
    }

   p4
   {
    color:rgb(136, 138, 140);
    text-transform:none;
    font-size:0.6em;
    font-weight:normal;
    display:inline-block;
    width:72%;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding-top:5px;
    max-width:474px;
    }
```

And HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 marg"> 
        <h6 class="pad"> Szkolenia pierwszej pomocy </h6> <img src="images/doctor-suitecase-64.png" id="icon"> <p4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum ante ut commodo lacinia. Aliquam id felis faucibus, mollis tortor vitae, mollis ante.  </p4>       <div class="more"> Czytaj więcej... </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 marg"> 
        <h6 class="pad"> Tworzenie dokumentacji </h6> <img src="images/text-file-5-64.png" id="icon"> <p4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum ante ut commodo lacinia. Aliquam id felis faucibus, mollis tortor vitae, mollis ante.  </p4>    <div class="more"> Czytaj więcej... </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 marg"> 
        <h6 class="pad"> Kontrola jakości <br> </h6> <img src="images/workers-64.png" id="icon"> <p4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum ante ut commodo lacinia. Aliquam id felis faucibus, mollis tortor vitae, mollis ante.  </p4> <div     class="more"> Czytaj więcej... </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you use "col-sm-12" for mobile devices? I see col-md-4 is used for desktop. If col-sm-12 is used in mobile it will show each below one by one

Comment: The HTML is invalid. There is no such element as `<p4>`

Comment: An image of what this is **suppposed** to look like would he helpful here.

Comment: I believe you can use even something like p9 and it will work as long as you style it properly. It works well for me, so I don't think it's invalid. 

You see these icons and lorem ipsum paragraphs? They all should be in one line. That's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. This will work in your case

**Html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 marg"> 
        <h3 class="pad1"> Szkolenia pierwszej pomocy </h3>
        <img src="images/doctor-suitecase-64.png" id="icon">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum ante ut commodo lacinia. Aliquam id felis faucibus, mollis tortor vitae, mollis ante.  </p>
        <div class="more"> Czytaj więcej... </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 marg"> 
        <h3 class="pad2"> Tworzenie dokumentacji</h3>
        <img src="images/text-file-5-64.png" id="icon">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum ante ut commodo lacinia. Aliquam id felis faucibus, mollis tortor vitae, mollis ante.</p>
        <div class="more"> Czytaj więcej... </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 marg"> 
        <h3 class="pad3"> Kontrola jakości</h3>
        <img src="images/workers-64.png" id="icon">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum ante ut commodo lacinia. Aliquam id felis faucibus, mollis tortor vitae, mollis ante.</p>
        <div class="more"> Czytaj więcej... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).resize(function () {
            var heig1 = $(".pad1").height();
            var heig2 = $(".pad2").height();
            var heig3 = $(".pad3").height();
            var lrg = Math.max(heig1, heig2, heig3);
            if(lrg == heig1){
                $(".pad2,.pad3").height(lrg);
            }
            else if(lrg == heig2){
                $(".pad1,.pad3").height(lrg);
            }
            else{
                $(".pad1,.pad2").height(lrg);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works almost perfectly. With one exception. It works only for the two columns on the right. It's probably because the first one is let's say '3 words high'. I'll study the code you gave me and try to solve it.

By the way, how can I vertically align this third heading to be in the middle. Now it's kinda on the top and I want it to be centered. I know that there is something like vertical align, but as far as  I am concerned it works only for tables. Position absolute/relative doesn't seem to be very helpful as well here.

Comment: This will work for all the three column. This code is targeting the two lowest height.
For vertically align in the middle, just use the CSS

`h3 {
    height: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
}`

Comment: But it works only for one row. Is there any more efficient way to make it work for 4, the same rows than just writing the same code and changing the "pad1, pad2, pad3," to "pad4, pad5, pad6" and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to look into flexbox as this might solve your problem. Flexbox has flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis (or the shorthand, flex) that can solve this problem you have. It helped me with a similar issue.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/kv7tbhaq/3/)

What you have to is, just use **bootstrap grids** properly like,

**Sample HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h3>This is the heading and I like it very much than anything</h3>
            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I am concerned that doesn't solve the problem. It just changes the order of the elements. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Have you check the fiddle..? if not then do visit, I think it will solve your problem (try to resize the result tab there)